# Entity Framework 4 + POCO with custom classes and WCF contracts (serialization problem)

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, poco

Yesterday I worked on a project where I upgraded to [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) 4 with the Repository pattern. In one post, I have read that it is necessary to turn off the custom tool generator classes and then write classes (same like entites) by hand. That I can do it, I used the [POCO Entity Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313) and then deleted the new generated files .tt and all subordinate .cs classes. Then I wrote the "entity classes" by myself.

I added the repository pattern and implemented it in the business layer and then implemented a WCF layer, which should call the methods from the business layer. By calling an Insert (Add) method from the presentation layer and everything is OK. But if I call any method that should return some class, then I get an error like (the connection was interrupted by the server).

I suppose there is a problem with the serialization or am I wrong? How can by this problem solved?

I'm using Visual Studio S2010, Entity Framework 4, C#.

**UPDATE:**

I have uploaded the project and hope somebody can help me! [link text](http://jump.fm/ARLLE)

**UPDATE 2:**

My questions:

1. Why is [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) good (pros/cons)?
2. When should POCO be used?
3. Is POCO + the repository pattern a good choice?
4. Should POCO classes by written by myself or could I use auto generated POCO classes?

Comment: It's better to insert your code here

Comment: Post Updated and added source code!

Comment: I think you might be confused. You need to role your own entity classes yourself if you decide to use code first. Right? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have added some questions and hope to get answers to solve my problems.

Comment: Please narrow this down and ask one specific question at a time. Voting to close as "Not a real question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is POCO good (pros/cons)?

- Work with EF4, NH and few others -ORM

When should POCO be used?

- Depends on [usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966797/ef4-difference-between-poco-self-tracking-entities-poco-proxies)

Is POCO + the repository pattern a good choice?

- For WCF

  POCO- You have track changes manually,

  STE Automatic Change Tracking is done.

Should POCO classes by written by myself or could I use auto generated POCO classes?

- T4 would be better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your WCF serialization issues, in the t4 template, we needed to set the ProxyCreationEnabled = false; on the ContextOptions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontextoptions.proxycreationenabled.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For POCO serialization you'll need the ProxyDataContractResolver.

You may wnat to check out [this MSDN Walkthrough article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.proxydatacontractresolver.aspx) on building a custom attribute that you can apply to your service contract to serialize the POCO proxy types.